# R and power for one-tailed t-test

Tags: r

I'll be running a one-tailed t-test to determine if one mean is significantly lower than another. The problem is that, when I use *R*'s *pwr* package to determine what power I can expect with *n*=30, I get an extremely low power even for large effects. So, for example:

```
> pwr.t.test(d=0.8,sig.level=.05,n=30,alternative="less")

  Two-sample t test power calculation 

             n = 30
             d = 0.8
     sig.level = 0.05
         power = 1.251823e-06
   alternative = less

  NOTE: n is number in *each* group
```

What's even stranger is that, when I increase *n*, the power goes down. So, for example, upping *n* to 300 gives me this:

```
> pwr.t.test(d=0.8,sig.level=.05,n=300,alternative="less")

  Two-sample t test power calculation 

             n = 300
             d = 0.8
     sig.level = 0.05
         power = 0
   alternative = less

  NOTE: n is number in *each* group
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's because d and alternative = 'less' are on different 'directions'. 
Try this, and you will know what I mean.

```
pwr.t.test(d= - 0.8,sig.level=.05,n=300,alternative="less")

 Two-sample t test power calculation 

          n = 300
          d = -0.8
  sig.level = 0.05
      power = 1
alternative = less

NOTE: n is number in *each* group
```